# Adb Server Version Doesn't Match This Client [React Native]

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu-16.04

I am currently facing an issue with setting up android's development environment for development with react native, whenever I run `react-native run-android` i get the following error `adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...` I am not using Genymotion, all the solutions I saw online were for people who use Genymotion, I am testing directly on a USB connected device running Android 6.0 Marshmallow, and my PC is running 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured, obviously I had two installations of adb, one comes with the android sdk and the other installed from the apt-get repo so all I had to do was delete the one I installed form the apt-get repo, there are two of them actually `android-platform-adb` and `adb` so i just did `apt-get remove android-platform-adb`and now I'm back to developing for android on Ubuntu. :)